# Parquet file name in Azure Data Factory

Tags: parquet, azure-data-factory

I'm copying data from an Oracle DB to ADLS using a copy activity of  Azure Data Factory. 
The result of this copy is a parquet file that contains the same data of the 
table that I have copied but the name of this resultant parquet file is like this:

```
data_32ecaf24-00fd-42d4-9bcb-8bb6780ae152_7742c97c-4a89-4133-93ea-af2eb7b7083f.parquet
```

And I need that this name is stored like this:

`TableName-Timestamp.parquet`

How can I do that with Azure Data Factory?

Another question: Is there a way to add hierarchy when this file is being written? For example, I use the same 
pipeline for writting several tables and I want to create a new folder for each table. I can do that if I create a new Dataset for each table 
to write, but I want to know if is there a way to do that automatically (Using dynamic content).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi AngryCoder, If my answer is helpful for you, you can mart it  as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, it was very helpful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a pipeline parameter to achieve it.

Here's the  example I tried copy data from Azure SQL database to ADLS,  it also should works for oracle to ADLS.

**Set pipeline parameter:** set the Azure SQL/Oracle table name which need to copy to ADLS:

[image]

**Source dataset:**

Add dynamic content to set table name:

[image]

**Source:**

Add dynamic content: set table name with pipeline parameter:
[image]

**Sink dataset:**

Add dynamic content to set Parquet file name:

[image]

**Sink:**

Add dynamic content to set Parquet file name with pipeline parameter:

Format: TableName-Timestamp.parquet:

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.tablename,'-',utcnow())
```

Then execute the pipeline, you will get the Parquet file like `TableName-Timestamp.parquet`:

About your another question:

You could add dynamic content set folder name for each table, just follow this:

[image]

For example, if we copy the table "test", the result we will get:

```
container/test/test-2020-04-20T02:01:36.3679489Z.parquet
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really Helped me today